# MacOS: Create a raw (dd) Image of an APFS volume

Tags: macos, dd, disk-image, sparsebundle

I have a .sparsebundle and I would like to convert it to something that can be used outside of the apple bubble. APFS/HFS is supported by a bunch of tools, but sadly the image formats are not from what I know.

The main issue is, that the .sparsebundle has a limit of 4TB, but the volume within only of about 400GB. a full dd is not possible without buying a huge disk as well as and spending a lot of time and it would be a huge waste of storage anyway.

if I try to dd the Volume of the synthesized disk I get *Permission denied*

I already disabled SIP (Win+R for recovery mode, csrutil disable, reboot, verify using csrutil status) and I added the dd binary to the list of tools that should have full disk access in

> Apple - system configuration - Security - Privacy - Full disk access

(Names might not be fully correct, as I do not use an English MacOS)
To achieve this I copied /bin/dd to /dd, because /bin/ seems to be inaccessible for this setting

If I try rsync to logically copy the contents of the sparsebundle I get > 900GiB (and still counting), probably because the destination file system does not support hard links.

Comment: Where is this sparesebundle located? Was it created using Time Machine, or something else?

Comment: @JMY1000 in Time Machine it would be a .backupbundle, wouldn't it? I actually have no idea about where it was stored originally.

Comment: Prior to Catalina, Time Machine used spsrsebundles. Do you know what’s in it/how it was made?